# UDK iOS: System Requirements confusion

Tags: iphone, unreal

Unreal Development Kit for iOS was recently released. The system requirements note that Windows is needed. Does this mean that iOS game development is possible on a PC now?

I am confused since I thought iOS development required an OSX machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As Tim Holt mentioned you will need a PC to run the Unreal Editor to create your content. It also allows you to test your game in an emulator or transfer the content to your iPhone. BUT, to submit your application you will need a Mac.

The following [documentation](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/GettingStartediOSDevelopment.html) page explains all this.

Also don't forget that you will need to be a registered iOS developer - meaning pay the $99/year to be able to even test application on your iPhone. This process for Provisioning is explained in the following two documentation pages:

- [iOS Provisioning Overview](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/AppleiOSProvisioning.html)
- [iOS Provisioning Setup](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/AppleiOSProvisioningSetup.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need Windows to run the Unreal Editor to create content.  Build the game on Windows, export to iOS.